# java how to make a field not cloneable

Tags: java, cloneable

For serialization, transient fields will be excluded. Is there any similar keyword for clone? How to exclude a field from clone?

```
public class Foo implements Cloneable {
    private Integer notInClone;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you *must* implement `clone()` if you want it to be public (it's not part of `Cloneable` interface, and is `protected` in the `Object`) you will have an opportunity to clear out the unwanted fields in your code:

```
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Foo res = (Foo)super.clone();
    res.notInClone = null;        // Do the cleanup for fields that you wish to exclude
    return res;
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/HMyR6J)

Comment: `Since you must implement clone()...`  In general, this is not a requirement since there is a default `clone()` method in `Object`. For this particular requirement, then "must" is correct.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice You are right, I need to qualify this statement, because a class could legitimately keep `clone()` protected for internal use. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 4):

There is no specific annotation that can do that to my knowledge.

You could override the `Object#clone` method, and selectively set the non-cloneable fields' values to `null` on the returned `Object` after casting.

The cloned object will still feature the field since it should be casted explicitly to the same class, but that value will be `null`.